# Non-alphanumeric characters in maven classifier

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

We're having a dot in our classifier (wf-8.2) and our local nexus repository reports the type of the artifact to be `2.jar`. Can this cause a problem somewhere, or is this just a bug of the nexus?

e.g.:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <classifier>wf-8</classifier>
  <type>2.jar</type>
</dependency>
```

We can use the artifact by specifying the dependency's classifier as `wf-8.2`, but I'm wondering whether we are using invalid character(s), but couldn't find any info on this.

Comment: Seems like it was fixed https://issues.sonatype.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/NEXUS-4766

Comment: We're using  Sonatype Nexus™ 2.1.2. That issue is for 1.9.x, also the artifacts are right (I mean the actual filenames/extensions).

Comment: Use 2.1.2 of nexus is a little bit out of date (2.11.4 is up-to-date). Furthermore a dash in a classifier will not work, cause the naming is `artifactId-version[-classifier].ext`. Furthermore a type `2.jar` does not make sense. `jar` makes sense...which is default...Why not using `wf8` as classifier?

Comment: I'm aware that our nexus is a bit outdated. I don't understand why shouldn't a dash work, because for example artifactIds can have dashes, eg: commons-lang... The dependency declaration is what our nexus suggests to use. Of course we're using it as a jar (without type declared). It seems to me, that the nexus is having problem defining the type (although we can download the artifact itself, with proper dependency declaration).

Comment: There is a difference between classifier and artifactId...

Comment: Is there any official or unofficial documentation about what characters should and shouldn't be used in artifact names/version numbers/classsifiers/etc? (this is the real question here for me, I guess)